# Как изменить поле объекта в массиве redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня есть редьюсер который добавляет данные из стороннего апи в стор и я так же хочу через экшн изменить поле определенного объекта по которому кликаю, в данном случае поле isLike изначально равно false. Из компонента через диспатч я передаю значение true. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, только начал разбираться с редаксом и не совсем понятно, как правильно изменять стейт

```
const LIKE = 'LIKE'
const ADD_CARDS = 'ADD_CARDS'

let initialState = {
  cards: []
}

const cardsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_CARDS:
      return {...state, cards: action.payload}
    case LIKE:
      return {...state, cards: {...state.cards, isLike: action.payload}}
    default:
      return state
  }
}


export const likeChanger= (payload) => ({type: LIKE, payload})

export const addCardsCreator = (payload) => ({type: ADD_CARDS, payload})

export default cardsReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cards` - это массив объектов, у которых есть свойство `isLike` и, скорее всего, должно быть свойство `id`.

На действие `LIKE` нужно найти объект с нужным `id` и поменять у него `isLike` на противоположное.

```
case LIKE:
  return {
    ...state,
    cards: state.cards.map(
      card => card.id === action.payload
        ? {
          ...card,
          isLike: !card.isLike
        }
        : card
    ),
  }
```

В функцию `likeChanger` передается `id` элемента, который нужно обновить.

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек)